# Converges series test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges, where $ a_n\geq0$ for all $n\in \Bbb{N}$. Prove that 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}
$$ 
converges.

pf: I'm thinking this is a comparison test?

Answer (score 8):

**Hint**: Since $a_n \geq 0$ for every $n$, it must be the case that
\begin{equation}
\frac{a_n}{1 + a_n} \leq a_n.
\end{equation}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: a little bit more..please

Comment: Do you see a way to use my hint in conjunction with your idea of applying the comparison test?

Comment: @yoknapatawpha - mad respect for your username.

Comment: @john Do you know the conditions we need to use the comparison test? I think since $\sum a_n$ converges and $\frac{a_n}{1 + a_n} \leq a_n$, we can directly apply the comparison test to this fact alone.

Comment: $0 \leq \frac{a_n}{1+a_n} \leq a_n $ $ $ now that $a_n$ $ $ is converges then by comparison test $ $ $b_n = a_n$ so if $b_n$ is converges then $a_n$ is converges